# How to remove accent color in title bar of the window when that option is enabled in Windows 11 22H2?

Tags: .net, wpf, window-chrome

In Windows 11 22H2 Microsoft changed how option

> Settings > Personalization > Color > Show accent color in title bars
> and windows borders

works (compared to 21H2). Now it is forced on all windows.
Is it possible to disable it on custom windows?

I expected that `CaptionHeight` would control this, but makes no difference.

```
<WindowChrome                    
    CaptionHeight="0" 
    GlassFrameThickness="-1"
    UseAeroCaptionButtons="True" />
```

`TitleBar.Height` is not changeable.

Any other suggestions or is it a bug in Windows 11 so the Mica effect can be applied on the entire window including the title bar?

Comment: As a user, there is nothing I dislike more than when an app ignores a system (or better: user) preference. Also: there is apparenlty a bug in Windows 11 22H2 which makes many apps (like Notepad and Explorer) ignore this setting, seemingly on random base: some days the use the accent color in the title bar, some days they don't.

Comment: As a possible workaround, set the color of the caption to 0x202020 or 0xF3F3F3 based if it's dark or light theme.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `AppWindow` class in the [Windows App SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK/) to change the colour of the title bar, e.g.:

```
Microsoft.Windows.ApplicationModel.DynamicDependency.Bootstrap.TryInitialize(0x00010000, out _);
var hWnd = new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(this).EnsureHandle();
var windowId = Microsoft.UI.Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(hWnd);
var appWindow = Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(windowId);
if (appWindow != null)
{
    appWindow.TitleBar.BackgroundColor = Microsoft.UI.Colors.Red;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to use Microsoft.UI in .NET Framework 4.8